# How can I make a window always show the same file buffer?

Tags: buffers, window, find-file, dedicated-windows

How can I force Emacs to keep a certain file in a particular window? For example, if I am editing a LaTeX file and there is a compile error, I want to inspect the error in another window. I essentially want to "freeze" a file in a window until I explicitly delete the window.

The expected behavior would also open up new files with `C-x C-f` in a different window, even if the command was initiated in my "frozen" window. Is there a way to do this?

What I want to do is something like this:

1. With two windows open, use one to edit a file.
2. With some command, freeze that window so that it always displays the file that I have just opened.
3. In the "frozen" window, execute a command such as `find-file` (`C-x C-f`) to open a new file. This should open the file in the other window.

Comment: This is not clear, probably because you don't use the right terminology. Maybe you mean "window" instead of "buffer"? Providing a more extended explanation  and an example of exactly what you are doing, what you see and what you would like to see instead, might help.

Comment: The question only makes sense if you assume that they meant window.

Comment: What @NickD said. I suspect that making the buffer's window *dedicated* is what you're looking for. That prevents other buffers from being displayed in that window. `(set-window-dedicated-p (get-buffer-window) t)`

Comment: Edited to use the correct terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you meant window instead of buffer... Do this when the file's buffer is current:

```lisp
(set-window-dedicated-p (get-buffer-window) t)
```